# Eliminar objetos que empiecen por una letra dentro de Arraylist/Iterator - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Tras buscar y no encontrar me dirijo a vosotros pos esta vía. Estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación, pero ya tengo problemas.

En este caso tengo que eliminar todos aquellos objetos de un **ArrayList** que empiecen por una letra, en este caso la 'a' (no va por parámetros ni nada), usando **Iterator** sé que tengo que usar **remove**, pero no se como obtener los objetos empezados con 'a' para después poder eliminarlos. Además debo usar los métodos **hasNext()** (en vez de **for**) y **next()**. El esqueleto que debo usar es el siguiente:

```
Iterator<People> it = listaIkea.iterator();
while(it.hasNext(){
System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
List<String> listaIkea = new ArrayList<String>(List.of("armario", "silla", "mesa", "almohada", "somier", "rotulador"));
```

Mi intención es que tras buscar objetos que empiecen por 'a' (armario y almohada) y eliminarlos con **remove**, me quede una lista de 4 objetos (silla, mesa, somier y rotulador).

¿Como puedo hacer la condición if si algún objeto empieza por 'a'? No puedo usar **for**. La intención es borrar un elemento a la vez que iteramos.

Gracias de antemano y un saludo!

Comment: "como obtener los objetos empezados con 'a'",  en este caso lo ideal es el método [startsWith()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente encontré lo que andaba buscando, así que lo escribo por aquí por si en un futuro alguien hace uso de ello.

```
List<String> listaIkea = new ArrayList<String>(List.of("armario", "silla", "mesa", "almohada", "somier", "rotulador"));

 Iterator<String> it = listaIkea.iterator();

     while(it.hasNext()) {
         String element = it.next();
         if(element.startsWith("a")) {
             itr.remove();
         }else {
             System.out.println(element);
         }

     }
```

Esta es la forma que yo buscaba para poder iterar un **Arraylist** creado con anterioridad. Simplemente creamos una variable **String** y jugamos con el método **startsWith** y así eliminamos aquellos objetos que comiencen por 'a'.

Comment: Es la forma mas rara de recorrer un array que he visto jaj vamos basta con añadir el else system.out a mi for y tinees lo mismo :P

Answer (score 3):

Sin usar un ciclo esta actividad la realizamos con un predicado, así

```
public static void removerPorPredicado() {
        List<String> listaIkea = new ArrayList<>();
        listaIkea.add("armario");
        listaIkea.add("silla");
        listaIkea.add("mesa");
        listaIkea.add("almohada");
        listaIkea.add("somier");
        listaIkea.add("rotulador");
        System.out.println(listaIkea.size());

        listaIkea.removeIf(p -> p.startsWith("a"));

        System.out.println(listaIkea.size());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Si tienes una lista de elementos puedes iterar sobre esta lista, para buscar los elementos que inicien con  `'a'` existe un método el cual realiza esta operación [**startsWith()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-)

al encontrar la coincidencia procedes a eliminarlos de la lista mediante [**remove()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-).

Este sería un ejemplo:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < listaIkea.size(); i++){
        if(listaIkea.get(i).startsWith("a")){ //Busca elementos que inicien con "a".
            //Remueve elemento de la lista.
            listaIkea.remove(i);
        }            
    }
```

de acuerdo a tu ejemplo la salida de lo anterior sería un ArrayList conteniendo los elementos que no inician con `'a'`:

```
silla
mesa
somier
rotulador
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Si en vez de utilizar for() usara un while(iter.hasNext()) siendo iter un iterator creado del arrayList listaIkea en el que no puedo disponer de un contador, ¿Como sería? Muchas gracias por responder.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es lo que tu quieres. Tu arraylist lo recorremos con un for y cada palabra que tenemos en el le hacemos un substring y sacamos su primera letra y la comparamos con la A ya se mayuscola o minuscula y si es la removemos

```
 List<String> listaIkea = new ArrayList<>();
       listaIkea.add("armario");
        listaIkea.add("silla");
        listaIkea.add("mesa");
        listaIkea.add("almohada");
        listaIkea.add("somier");
        listaIkea.add("rotulador");

     for(int i=0;i<listaIkea.size();i++) {
      String letra =  listaIkea.get(i).substring(0, 1);
        if(letra.compareToIgnoreCase("a")==0){
            listaIkea.remove(i);
        }
```

Comment: Si en vez de utilizar for() usara un while(iter.hasNext()) siendo iter un iterator creado del arrayList listaIkea en el que no puedo disponer de un contador, ¿Como sería? Muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: los array se recorren con for no con while no he visto nunca un array con while